# Reasons why the acked number could differ so much from the emitted number on a Storm Spout?

Tags: apache-storm

I am just learning Storm. I have a situation and I need to assess if there's a faulty configuration on the Storm Cluster.

My question is: Is there a visible issue if I see that the emitted number is much higher than the acked number on a Spout? Additionally, there are no failures.

Would like to understand on what scenarios something like this would happen.

***Image that shows Storm UI for the topology where you'll see the discrepancy between emitted and acked for the spout***

[image]